# Type system troubles: RankNTypes + Typeclasses

Tags: haskell, typeclass, higher-rank-types

I've been having some troubles with combining typeclasses with higher-rank types in haskell.

The project I'm working on is an interpreter based around an evaluation monad. I'm currently attempting to transition my central evaluation monad from a stack of transformers to a set of mtl constraints. Many of the functions I'm using have type signatures like:

```hs
(MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m, MonadState ProgState m) => <something involving m>
```

In addition, I'm placing higher-rank polymorphic functions inside of some datastructures, e.g.

```hs
data Foo = 
  ...
  | forall m. MonadReader Environment m, ..., ... => <something involving m>
```

I've been using several language extensions, but I think the relevant ones are `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, FlexibleContexts #-}`.

As part of this transition, I'm running into two type errors throughout the codebase, but there's one snippet which demonstrates both (below).

At the surface level, it'd be nice if I can fix these issues, but I feel that all these type errors are related to my lack of understanding of how higher-rank types in Haskell work, so if there are any papers or articles that you feel may help they'd be much appreciated.

#### The Problem

The below snippet demonstrates both type-errors I'm getting:

```hs
normSubst :: (MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m, MonadState ProgState m) => (Normal, String) -> Normal -> m Normal
normSubst (val, var) ty = case ty of 
  -- ...
  NormCoVal pats ty -> do
    let pats' = map substCoPat pats
    ty' <- normSubst (val, var) ty
    pure (NormCoVal pats' ty')
```

Relevant type signatures include:

```hs
data Normal = 
 ...
 | NormCoVal (forall m. (MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m, MonadState ProgState m) => [(CoPattern, m Normal)]) Normal


substCoPat :: (MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m, MonadState ProgState m) => (CoPattern, m Normal) -> (CoPattern, m Normal)
```

#### Error 1

This error seems to be related to the line `let pats' = map substCoPat pats`, and has occurred a couple times. Several of these seem related to uses of combinators from the `Lens` library.

```
error:
    • Could not deduce (MonadReader Environment m0)
        arising from a use of ‘substCoPat’
      from the context: (MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m,
                         MonadState ProgState m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   normSubst :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                                (MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m,
                                 MonadState ProgState m) =>
                                (Normal, String) -> Normal -> m Normal
        at src/Interpret/Eval.hs:386:1-128
      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
      Relevant bindings include
        pats' :: [(CoPattern, m0 Normal)]
```

#### Error 2

This error is related to the line `pure (NormCoVal pats' ty')`, specifically the `pats` variable.
I've found something relating to this second error
[here](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2012-August/103041.html), but can't quite make sense of what the article is saying.

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘m0’ with ‘m1’
      Expected: [(CoPattern, m1 Normal)]
        Actual: [(CoPattern, m0 Normal)]
        because type variable ‘m1’ would escape its scope
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall (m1 :: * -> *).
          (MonadReader Environment m1, MonadError String m1,
           MonadState ProgState m1) =>
          [(CoPattern, m1 Normal)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, these errors are caused by the monomorphism restriction.  It causes `pats'` to be assumed monomorphic for some unspecified monad `m0`.  In order to call `substCoPat` at this type, GHC goes looking for appropriate dictionaries for `m0`, which are nowhere to be found (Error 1).  And the use of `pats'` on the last line is too monomorphic.  It only works for that ambiguous monad `m0`, but you're using it in a context where in needs to work `forall m1. (...constraints...) => ...` for some fresh `m1` type variable (Error 2).

Just turn off the restriction with the `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestricition #-}`, and a proper polymorphic type for `pats'` will be inferred.

Alternatively, adding an explicit type signature:

```
  NormCoVal pats ty -> do
    let pats' :: (MonadReader Environment m, MonadError String m, MonadState ProgState m) => [(CoPattern, m Normal)]
        pats' = map substCoPat pats
    ty' <- normSubst (val, var) ty
    pure (NormCoVal pats' ty')
```

or avoiding the `let`:

```
  NormCoVal pats ty -> do
    ty' <- normSubst (val, var) ty
    pure (NormCoVal (map substCoPat pats) ty')
```

would work, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think the usual advice of "do not try to store type classes inside data types" applies in this case.

You can restructure your program like this:

```
normSubst :: 
  ( MonadReader Environment m
  , MonadError String m
  , MonadState ProgState m
  ) => (Normal m, String) -> Normal m -> m (Normal m)
normSubst (val, var) ty = case ty of 
  -- ...
  NormCoVal pats ty -> do
    let pats' = map substCoPat pats
    ty' <- normSubst (val, var) ty
    pure (NormCoVal pats' ty')
```

```
data Normal m = 
 ...
 | NormCoVal [(CoPattern, m (Normal m))] (Normal m)


substCoPat :: 
  ( MonadReader Environment m
  , MonadError String m
  , MonadState ProgState m
  ) => (CoPattern, m (Normal m)) -> (CoPattern, m (Normal m))
```

Comment: I think that mostly would work, but I think there's one or two places that might cause a problem. Notably, both my `ProgState` and `Environment` types contain values of the `Normal` type, so I'd have to parametrize the `Environment` type. on m. 

My monad type, expressed as a transformer would then be something like: `EvalT m = ReaderT (Environment (EvalT m)) (ExceptT ....)`. Which gives me the `Cycle in type synonym  declarations:` error. Any ideas/advice on how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use a newtype instead of a type synonym for `EvalT`. But that type looks pretty complicated. I wonder if there is not a better way to really simplify it, but I cannot help much with only this piece of code.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try this out. Do you have any resources that might explain the original type errors?